# How to download image and save this in Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-webservice

I want show posts into my application and my posts has title, description, image and more ...
I want when download and show posts images from server, download this in phone and when show again this images not downloaded again, just show this from mobile memory!

how can i it?

Answer (score 0):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is a library designed for load internet pictures for Android.It helps you to download picture from server and save it both in cache as well as in SD Card.And most important of all,it is really easy to use:

```
Glide.with(context).load(pictureUrl).into(imageView);
```

Once you load a picture for once,the library create a link between **pictureUrl** and the picture itself.Next time you want to load the picture again,the library look for it in cache firstly rather than download it again.

Comment: I can use Glide library, but i don't know how can i save image in SD card and use it again . can uoy help me?

Comment: If you only want to load the picture again,just use the code I displayed above and the library will load the picture linked with the url from SDCard or from cache rather than download it from internet.